# Match if-statement conditions with user input sentence (reduce multiple conditions)

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I am new to the world of Python 3, and I need some help!

I am trying to create a text adventure game. The user will have four options:

```
1) You open the letter, you are too curious! 
2) You do not want to miss class, so you put it in your backpack. 
3) You think this is not real and quite ridiculous, so you throw it in the bin. 
4) You definitely want to open this together with {Friend_name}!
```

For each option, I have used if-statements within a while loop because if there is by any chance a wrong input, I want to ask the question again. This is the sample code of the first two options:

```
while True:
    first_choice = input(prompt ="What is your choice?  - ")

    if first_choice == "1" or first_choice == "open" or first_choice == "letter" or first_choice == "open letter" or first_choice == "are too curious" or first_choice == "curious"
        print(f"""
        You call {Friend_name over}, who was waiting for you in the hall. 
        You rip the letter open and....""")
        break

   elif first_choice == "2"or first_choice == "do" or or first_choice == "not" or or first_choice == "miss" or or first_choice == "class" or or first_choice == "miss class" 
        print("Class turned to be very boring" )
        break
```

A few of the matching examples are mentioned for options 1 and 2.
**Is there a better way to define the different possible *string* conditions within the if-statement?**
Other than:

```
    if first_choice == "1" or first_choice == "open" or first_choice == "letter" or 
    first_choice == "open letter" or first_choice == "are too curious" or first_choice 
    == "curious"
```

**If so, what should I do, and would the structure of the code change?**
**P.S, the user should be able to put in something else than just numbers 1 or 2. That is a requirement of the game, unfortunately.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think you need a parser that will process your input

Comment: Some questions:
1) Will your options change, like 1) I open the box, I am too curius... like that?
2) Is it "open letter" instead of "open the letter"?

Comment: @jasonwong. So the user should be able to enter everything. if the option is " You open the letter, you are too curious!",  the user could put in: open letter, open the letter, open, letter, too curious. I feel like the options that they can use to refer to the first options are endless.  I need to make sure that Python recognizes all these options and assign them to the right choice. So asking them a question like " do you mean ".........." instead would work as well but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: @whoami my apologies, I have no clue what a parser is and how to use it. Do you perhaps have an example? Thank you!

Comment: @EstrellaSpaans here the link that is related to what is parsing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing also take a look at this tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to for each of questions put expected answers in a list and then check whether a value is in that list like so:

```
expected_replies_1 = ['1', 'open', 'letter', 'open letter',]
first_choice = input(prompt ="What is your choice?  - ")

if first_choice in expected_replies_1:
    do stuff...
```

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps this is a stupid question but how would the elif look like? elif first_choice in expected_replies_2? (another list) Or a new if statement within the if statement (nested)?

Comment: Yeah, same structure in elif as in if.

Comment: That doesn't sound good as this require a long list of hand coded expected replies. What if you change the original text or the original text is very long?

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Does it fix your needs?

```py
if first_choice in ("1", "open", "letter", "open letter", "are too curious", "curious"):
    #process code
```

Comment: do you perhaps know what the structure would look like with the second choice? Same structure? Is it with elif? or another if statement?

Comment: Yeah, you use if-elif-else, and put all your options in the tuple